# Install Pecl PAM authentication Apache

Tags: php, debian, apache-2.4, pecl, pear

I want to setup horde webmail 5.2.9 on my server (debian Jessie).
When I go to `localhost/horde/test.ph`p I get:

```
PAM Support (PECL extension): No
  The PAM PECL extension is required to allow PAM authentication to be used.
```

To install the PAM extension, I have done the following:

```
# sudo pecl install --alldeps PAM
```

I can verify that PAM is installed:

```
# sudo pecl list
Installed packages, channel pecl.php.net:
=========================================
Package   Version State
pam       1.0.3   stable
```

I have also installed the following:

- libapache2-mod-authnz-pam
- pwauth
- libapache2-mod-authnz-external

I also have the following modules enabled:
 - authnz_external
 - authnz_pam

But when I go to phpinfo.php I don't see any PAM module or section.
Of course I restarted the Apache and even rebooted the server.
What's next?

Comment: after your install have you add "extension=pam.so" to your php.ini ?(restart apache after that).

Comment: Which php version have you use?